# The support of functions of two measures

Tags: measure-theory

Given two measures $P, Q$, on potentially different supports and a function $f$

that applies on them like $f(P, Q)$, what are the characterization or geometric interpretation of the set of all functions $f$s, which

- produce a new measure
- and its support is the union of the supports of $P$ and $Q$?

(In terms of terminology, not sure if $f$ is called a function, an operator, or a functional. but I mean something that returns a new measure and depends on P and Q.)

Comment: Support $P \times Q$ isn't union of supports of $P$ and $Q$. Did you mean product?

Comment: I think my example is then wrong. No, I was interested in union support only. I will edit.

Comment: I think there is a simple characterization: $f(x,y)=ax+by$ with $a, b >0$. (Assuming that you are dealing with positive measures).

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  I see. So no other possibility except that? Any hints on how to prove that is the only case?